# Using a specific data frame row entry to extract a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a fileA, which is a basic data frame with many columns.

```
  CHR         SNP       BP  NMISS       BETA       SE        R2       T      P
  22  rs62224314 16057427  118667  0.0064970 0.006882 7.512e-06  0.9442 0.3451
  22 rs200923414 16287551  119802 -0.1338000 0.229400 2.839e-06 -0.5832 0.5598
  22 rs138257221 16449078  119886  0.1082000 0.223600 1.954e-06  0.4840 0.6284
  22 rs149999112 16449613      0         NA       NA        NA      NA     NA
```

etc

and fileB, which is a one line file that is space separated and looks like this

```
  CHR SNP BP P
```

I want to use the values in fileB to extract the appropriate columns in fileA, using R.  The script I have so far is this:

```
## read in data file, must have tab separators and header
orig_data = read.table("fileA.txt", header=TRUE,sep="")

## read in column names
names_keep = read.table("fileB.txt", header=F,sep="")

w <- names_keep$V1
x <- names_keep$V2
y <- names_keep$V3
z <- names_keep$V4
```

When I check these values:

```
> w
[1] CHR
Levels: CHR
> x
[1] SNP
Levels: SNP
> y
[1] BP
Levels: BP
> z
[1] P
Levels: P
```

It seems to be doing what I want (extracting these 4 values from fileB).

However, when I try to extract these specific columns from the fileA dataframe using these 4 values:

```
newdata <- orig_data[,c(w,x,y,z)]
```

I just get the first column repeated 4 times:

```
  CHR CHR.1 CHR.2 CHR.3
1  22    22    22    22
2  22    22    22    22
3  22    22    22    22
4  22    22    22    22
```

When I want the output to look like:

```
  CHR         SNP       BP  P
  22  rs62224314 16057427  0.3451
  22 rs200923414 16287551  0.5598
  22 rs138257221 16449078  0.6284
  22 rs149999112 16449613      NA
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Comment: names_keep = read.table("keepnames.txt", header=F, as.is=T)

Comment: They are `factor` class, instead of `character`. The internal representation is used to subset. Verify with `R> c(w,x,y,z)`, the output will be `[1] 1 1 1 1`